# Remove url request paramters when changing state in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My current url is off the form below:

```
abc.com?authCode=value#/state1
```

Now I am doing a state change (angular-ui-router) to go to a send state(I am also sending some state params):

```
 $state.go("state1", { 'data': 'abc' });
```

Now I want a way to remove the url request parameter authcode when this state change occurs.
So after state change I want the url to be `abc.com#/state2` instead of `abc.com?authCode=value#/state2`

Comment: What is your **<base href=" "/>** ?

Comment: could you show sample code...

Comment: we dont have any <base>. I am just trying to find a way to remove request parameters on changing state. Our code just simply has states defined. I am doing a state.go from one state to another. I am seeing if there is any code I can add which removes the parameters when a certain state is hit